# to look at the suffix of the text of the text field

Tags: xcode, xcode10, suffix

I want to let the people login to the certain domain, but it always shows a error.

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int').

how can I deal with it?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {




    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }else{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createdUser", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }else{
            var hi = self.emailTextField.text

            if hi?.suffix("@hkugac.edu.hk"){ //error here


                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logged", sender: self)
        }


            }

        }
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hasSuffix method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1541149-hassuffix

```
var hi = self.emailTextField.text

if let mail = hi, mail.haSuffix("@hkugac.edu.hk")
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logged", sender: self)
}
else
{
    // Dome some error handling here.
}
```

Also, I think it would be better to check the mail *before* you call the signIn function.